# Unable to find minus() of Path in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas, android-jetpack-compose-path

I am trying to use [this minus extension function of Path](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Path#(android.graphics.Path).minus(android.graphics.Path)) in Jetpack Compose code.

But I am getting an unresolved reference error.

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun PathDiff() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        val rect1 = Path().also {
            it.addRect(Rect(Offset.Zero, Offset(100.0F, 100.0F)))
            it
        }
        val rect2 = Path().also {
            it.addRect(Rect(Offset(50.0F, 50.0F), Offset(150.0F, 150.0F)))
            it
        }

        drawPath(
            path = rect1 - rec2,
            color = Black,
            alpha = 1F,
        )
    }
}
```

**Dependency version**

```
jetpackComposeVersion = "1.3.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$rootProject.jetpackComposeVersion"
```

**Error**

```
e: /Users/abhimanyu/Documents/projects/stackoverflow-answers/codebase/android/app/src/main/java/com/makeappssimple/abhimanyu/stackoverflowanswers/android/MainActivity.kt: (375, 26): Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.minus(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
public inline operator fun BigInteger.minus(other: BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(element: TypeVariable(T)): List<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Array<out TypeVariable(T)>): List<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>): List<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>): List<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.minus(key: TypeVariable(K)): Map<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.minus(keys: Array<out TypeVariable(K)>): Map<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.minus(keys: Iterable<TypeVariable(K)>): Map<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.minus(keys: Sequence<TypeVariable(K)>): Map<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Set<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(element: TypeVariable(T)): Set<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Set<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Array<out TypeVariable(T)>): Set<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Set<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>): Set<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Set<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>): Set<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun <T> Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(element: TypeVariable(T)): Sequence<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.sequences
public operator fun <T> Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Array<out TypeVariable(T)>): Sequence<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.sequences
public operator fun <T> Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>): Sequence<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.sequences
public operator fun <T> Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>.minus(elements: Sequence<TypeVariable(T)>): Sequence<TypeVariable(T)> defined in kotlin.sequences
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Path.combine(PathOperation.Difference, path1, path2)

```
@Composable
fun PathDiff() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
    ) {
        val rect1 = Path().apply {
            addRect(Rect(Offset.Zero, Offset(100.0F, 100.0F)))

        }
        val rect2 = Path().apply {
            addRect(Rect(Offset(50.0F, 50.0F), Offset(150.0F, 150.0F)))

        }

       val newPath = Path.combine(PathOperation.Difference, path1 = rect1, path2 = rect2)

        drawPath(
            path = newPath,
            color = Color.Black,
            alpha = 1F,
        )
    }
}
```

or

```
var newPath= Path()

newPath.op(path1, path2, PathOperation.Difference)
```

Comment: This works as required. But still, I would like to know why `minus()` is not working. 

Comment: You can only use pat1.op(pat1, path2, PathOpertation.Difference) either but this is how they did it in Compose ✌️

Comment: Still confused . The Docs linked is compose `Path` docs. The `minus` is an extension operator function. And I am using the latest version.

Comment: My bad, went through the source code and found that the `minus()` is in `androidx.core.graphics` package and not the compose one.

Comment: The docs were confusing. 